# A question about $\pi$

Tags: pi

Is it correct?

$$\pi=3+\cfrac{\log(\frac{1}{\Delta})}{\log(\frac{1}{\Delta^{\sqrt{\Omega}}})},$$

with $$\Omega=\cfrac{1}{(\pi-3)^{2}}\thickapprox49.8790939?$$

Comment: Yes. But this question isn't really about $\pi$.

Comment: What's $\Delta$? Of course it can be anything, since the fraction you write is just $\sqrt{\Omega}$, so you've written $\pi=3+(\pi-3)$, which is not really new.

Comment: Everything is new above all $\sqrt{\Omega}$ is new

Answer (score 6):

For sure:

$$
3+\frac{\log(\frac{1}{\Delta})}{\log(\frac{1}{\Delta^\sqrt{\Omega}})}=3+\frac{\log(\frac{1}{\Delta})}{\sqrt{\Omega}\log(\frac{1}{\Delta})}=3+\frac{1}{\sqrt{\Omega}}=3+\pi - 3 = \pi
$$

Comment: easy life. Where is my points???